# How do I tell awk to use = as a separator (with white spaces removed too)

Tags: awk

Suppose I have the following file.

```
John=good
Tom   = ok
Tim =    excellent
```

I know the following let's me use `=` as a separator.

```
awk -F= '{print $1,$2}' file
```

This gives me the following results.

```
John good
Tom     ok
Tim      excellent
```

I would like the white spaces to be ignored, so that only the names and their performances are printed out.

One way to get around this is run another `awk` on the results.

```
awk -F= '{print$1,$2}' file | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

But I wanted to know if I could do this in one `awk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include them in the separator definition; it's a regexp.

```
jinx:1654 Z$ awk -F' *= *' '{print $1, $2}' foo.ds
John good
Tom ok
Tim excellent
```

Answer (score 1):

The FS variable can be set to a regular expression.

From the AWK manual

```
The following table summarizes how fields are split, based on the value of FS.

FS == " "
    Fields are separated by runs of whitespace. Leading and trailing whitespace are ignored. This is the default. 
FS == any single character
    Fields are separated by each occurrence of the character. Multiple successive occurrences delimit empty fields, as do leading and trailing occurrences. 
FS == regexp
    Fields are separated by occurrences of characters that match regexp. Leading and trailing matches of regexp delimit empty fields.
```